# users.get - аватар в https

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Метод `users.get` на сайте документации в калькуляторе выдает аватарки на https, вида

```
https://pp.vk.me/c306801/v306801932/25e3/xxxxxx.jpg
```

а на моем сайте, где *api* используется для авторизации, такой же запрос выдает аватарки на http вида

```
http://cs306801.vk.me/v306801932/25e3/xxxxxx.jpg
```

Я сменил версию *API* в запросе на последнюю, но это никак не влияет.

Судя по всему, адрес аватарки можно сконвертировать на лету, но хотелось бы, чтобы *API* выдавал сразу https адрес.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Напишите им в техподдержку

Comment: Вероятно ответ зависит от протокола сайта с которого приходит запрос.
Протокол сайта с которого Вы тестируете - https?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить аватарку по https необходимо явно указывать параметр https=1 при запросе. Вот здесь https://vk.com/dev/api_requests в разделе "Передача параметров в API":

> https – 1 — позволяет получать https ссылки на фотографии и другое медиа. 0 - методы возвращают http ссылки (по умолчанию). Обратите внимание, что этот параметр работает только если запросы к API осуществляются через https.